# Format amount in Canadian for finance area

Tags: java, format, locale, currency

I am trying to format an amount for Canadian locale 'en_CA' for finances area.
But in java, it uses the `¤#,##0.00` pattern for 'en_CA' locale. This pattern is correct but is used for general texts.
In the area of finance, it should be another pattern with whitespace after a currency symbol.
 Like  `¤ #,##0.00`.
For example: `CAD 125,456.00`
I've tried this way:

```
DecimalFormat currencyInstance = ( DecimalFormat ) DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance( new Locale( "en", "CA" ) );
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = currencyInstance.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
decimalFormatSymbols.setCurrencySymbol( "CAD" );
currencyInstance.setDecimalFormatSymbols( decimalFormatSymbols );
System.out.println( currencyInstance.format( 123456 ) );
System.out.println( currencyInstance.toLocalizedPattern() ); // get pattern
```

I get result without whitespace:

```
CAD123,456.00
¤#,##0.00
```

So my question if Java contains a pattern for the 'en_CA' locale for **financial area**? How can I find it?
I know that I can set my own pattern to DecimalFormat but I am looking for a solution when Java will provide that pattern for me.

Comment: if there is such `Locale` you find it in the class `Locale`

Comment: Java doesn't have that nuance.

Comment: Locale is to localize things (so in very local specific way, like dates). You just want to use a standardized way (ISO notation for currencies, like we have one for dates). So you can just format it yourself, because the string need not to be localized.